# Multi column search

Tags: php, sql, mysql, search

I have 4 text columns, a mix of Varchar and Text.  I need to find rows in a table where all words searched for are present across the 4 columns.

The 4 columns are:

- name
- type
- keywords
- description

So if someone searches for "london wildlife museum", it would only return rows where all words were found across the 4 columns.

Current code for managing the multiple words:

```
$words = $_GET['freetext'];
if(empty($words)){
//redirect somewhere else!
}
$parts = explode(" ",trim($words));
$clauses1=array();
foreach ($parts as $part){
    //function_description in my case ,  replace it with whatever u want in ur table
    $clauses1[]="vname LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($part) . "%'";
}
$clause1=implode(' OR ' ,$clauses1);

$parts = explode(" ",trim($words));
$clauses2=array();
foreach ($parts as $part){
    //function_description in my case ,  replace it with whatever u want in ur table
    $clauses2[]="vtype LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($part) . "%'";
}
$clause2=implode(' OR ' ,$clauses2);

$parts = explode(" ",trim($words));
$clauses3=array();
foreach ($parts as $part){
    //function_description in my case ,  replace it with whatever u want in ur table
    $clauses3[]="vdesc LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($part) . "%'";
}
$clause3=implode(' OR ' ,$clauses3);

$parts = explode(" ",trim($words));
$clauses4=array();
foreach ($parts as $part){
    //function_description in my case ,  replace it with whatever u want in ur table
    $clauses4[]="vkeywords LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($part) . "%'";
}
$clause4=implode(' OR ' ,$clauses4);
//select your condition and add "AND ($clauses)" .
$sql="SELECT vid, vname, vsuburb, vtype, vlogo, suburb.sname 
      FROM venue, suburb 
      WHERE
      venue.vsuburb = suburb.sid
      AND (($clause1) OR ($clause2) OR ($clause3) OR ($clause4))";
```

Obviously this creates a long list of `OR`s, but I can't see how to only choose the rows where all words appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you have a look at  MySQL's full-text search. Its a better approach then just combining each criteria. It do think it only works on MyISAM.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: and for innodb stuff look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381186/fulltext-search-with-innodb

Comment: Hi @Rogier, I had tried with this with no success, but went back and have managed to get it working. Major issue getting the Fulltext indexes across the columns but ended up working

Answer (score 1):

Easy! Change your ORs to ANDs so that the final statement reads:

Your statement essentially needs to look like this:

SELECT * FROM table

WHERE (vname LIKE '%value1%' OR vtype LIKE '%value1%' OR vdesc LIKE '%value1%')

AND (vname LIKE '%value2%' OR vtype LIKE '%value2%' OR vdesc LIKE '%value2%')

AND (vname LIKE '%value3%' OR vtype LIKE '%value3%' OR vdesc LIKE '%value3%')

so it ensures that value1 exists in one of the 4 fields, that value2 exists in one of the 4 fields, and value3 exists in one of the 4 fields, etc.

If that's not sufficient, use PHP to iterate a larger number of results and filter down the results.

```
$words = $_GET['freetext'];
if(empty($words)){
//redirect somewhere else!
}
$parts = explode(" ",trim($words));
$clauses1=array();
foreach ($parts as $part){
    //function_description in my case ,  replace it with whatever u want in ur table
    $clauses1[]="vname LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($part) . "%'";
}
$clause1=implode(' AND ' ,$clauses1);

$parts = explode(" ",trim($words));
$clauses2=array();
foreach ($parts as $part){
    //function_description in my case ,  replace it with whatever u want in ur table
    $clauses2[]="vtype LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($part) . "%'";
}
$clause2=implode(' AND ' ,$clauses2);

$parts = explode(" ",trim($words));
$clauses3=array();
foreach ($parts as $part){
    //function_description in my case ,  replace it with whatever u want in ur table
    $clauses3[]="vdesc LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($part) . "%'";
}
$clause3=implode(' AND ' ,$clauses3);

$parts = explode(" ",trim($words));
$clauses4=array();
foreach ($parts as $part){
    //function_description in my case ,  replace it with whatever u want in ur table
    $clauses4[]="vkeywords LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($part) . "%'";
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make it so it returns only when a single column has every word in the search query, not where every search query is found in a whole row?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response, but that requires that all words appear in one column together rather than spanned over all columns.

Comment: Hi @Johnnyoh yes, that's the problem

Comment: Look at my answer Deepweb.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ORs to ANDs on the final SQL statement.

```
$sql="SELECT vid, vname, vsuburb, vtype, vlogo, suburb.sname 
      FROM venue, suburb 
      WHERE
      venue.vsuburb = suburb.sid
      AND (($clause1) AND ($clause2) AND ($clause3) AND ($clause4))";
```

This would make the final query look something like this:

```
SELECT vid, vname, vsuburb, vtype, vlogo, suburb.sname 
FROM venue, suburb 
WHERE
venue.vsuburb = suburb.sid
AND
(vname = 'london' OR vname = 'wildlife' OR vname='museum') AND (vtype = 'london' OR vtype = 'wildlife' OR vtype ='museum') AND (vkeywords='london' OR vkeywords='wildlife' OR vkeywords='museum') AND (vdescription='london' OR vdescription='wildlife' OR vdescription='museum')
```

Comment: Sorry, @johnnyoh this means that one word of the phrase must appear in all columns

Answer (score 0):

+1 to *@Rogier*, full-text search seems the best solution. Another idea could be concatenating the `name`, `type`, `keywords` and `description` attributes and searching in the concatenated attribute:

```
SELECT ..., CONCAT_WS(' ', name, type, keywords, description) AS c
FROM ...
WHERE c LIKE '%value1%' AND c LIKE '%value2%' ...
```

It may possible to store the result of concatenation in a persistent attribute etc.

Comment: Concat is a good idea, fulltext using MATCH is working now